# Hyperlink functionality missing with javascript:history.go(-1) when used with anchor tag using csrf token

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, csrf

In my jsp page, i use the below code to prevent csrf attack.

```
out.println(" CLICK <csrf:a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1);\">HERE</csrf:a> To go back to previous page.");
```

When i use the above code, the hyperlink functionality is missing for "HERE" and is getting displayed as normal text without hyperlink functionality.

In the above code if i remove "csrf" for anchor tag, then every thing works well but at this line a csrf vulnerability is getting reported during the security scan.
Please suggest how could i use csrf tag in the above code, without missing hyperlink functionality.

Comment: What is the rendered HTML that appears to the user for this link?

Comment: CLICK <csrf:a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1);\">HERE</csrf:a> To go back to previous page. Attached the issue line of code which was missing in the post.

Comment: `<csrf:a ..` is not valid HTML format. Take away the `csrf:` part in see what happens

Comment: I am using the code in jsp there is no issues with csrf tag. for example the below code is working fine even with csrf. But the issue is when used csrf with javascript:history.go(-1) with the anchor tag. <%@ taglib uri="http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_CSRFGuard_Project/Owasp.CsrfGuard.tld" prefix="csrf" %>
<csrf:a href="/temp/index.jsp">Click here to go to index.jsp</csrf:a>